# Recursion: Find the sum of all possible k-permutations of a given digit array

Tags: c, recursion, sum, permutation

The problem I have goes like this:

For a given of array of different decimal digits (0,1,2,3...,8,9) write a recursive function that returns a sum of all natural numbers which are made of the given digits. E.g. for array {1,2} you would get 12 + 21 + 2 + 1 = 36

What I had in mind was if you have an array 1,2,3

You would "set aside" the last number and permute the smaller set that is left like this:

1. 1 2 3
2. 2 1 3
3. 2 3
4. 1 3
5. 3

Which would be 10 * [perm(1,2)] + 3 * (number of repetition)

This is my code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
int *temp=a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=*temp;
}

int rek(int n[], int d,int sum,int cnt)
{   cnt++;
if(d==0){return n[d];}
int i;
for(i=d;i>=0;i--)
{
    swap(&n[i],&n[d]);
    sum+=10+rek(n,d-1,sum,0)+n[d]*cnt;
    swap(&n[i],&n[d]);
}
return sum;
}


int main()
{
int a[9],k,i,s=0,error=0;
scanf("%d",&k);
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    if(i){if(a[i]==a[i-1]){error=1;} }
}
if(error){printf("Error!"); return 0;}

s+=rek(a,k-1,s,0);

printf("%d",s);

return 0;
}
```

It seems my swapping doesn't work, and I don't know why. I printed the array inside the rek function and for input {1,2} it should be once {1,2} the other time {2,1} but instead I get {1,2} and then {2,2}. I looked around on SO, but the only thing I could find is sum of all possible combinations that sum up to a certain number. I know this can be done without recursion with some combinatorial formulas but I'm interested in the recursive version.

Answer (score 1):

```
void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
int *temp=a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=*temp;
}
```

This will store the pointer `a` in `temp`, set *the value at `a`*, then read *the value at `temp`*. It still points to the same place, which now has a new value in it. You need to store the value itself in the temporary variable:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```